# C# WinForms how to have a console inside a form

Tags: .net, winforms, console, ascii, .net-7.0

So I'm working on a project called PteroController, and I'm trying to find a way to display a console inside a form, so I can show the console output I get from a web socket, which can be color coded by default using ASCII color codes. So what I need is a console inside a form that I can send output to.

I did not try some code but i looked everywhere!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680382/how-do-i-get-output-from-a-command-to-appear-in-a-control-on-a-form-in-real-time/51682585#51682585

Comment: If you want to show a Console window inside a Form, see: [Unhook Window into its original State](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65847818/7444103) -- **Read the notes there**

Comment: @Jimi i got to have a console so i can output my own output that i want and it can be colored output

Comment: Yep. That code is used to *embed* inside a Container (e.g., a Panel) any window that has a Handle (as the Console window). If you just want to show a Console to output some data and you don't need the *embedding* stuff, just use the `Process` class to execute cmd.exe or the [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/). Or maybe run a PowerShell script for the pre-processing, to just show the output in a Console window